# Access application data when extending embedded Python

Tags: python-c-api, python-embedding

I am writing an application that embeds a Python interpreter. The application also extends Python with a custom module. This is done along the lines of the ["Extending and Embedding the Python Interpreter" part of the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/index.html). In the section ["Extending Embedded Python"](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html#extending-embedded-python) they describe how to "access to functionality from the application" and the example module `emb` get access to `argv` of the application's `main` function by using a static variable `numargs`.

Now, my question is, can I somehow pass data (like `argv`) to my module in a more encapsulated way than using global state?

In contrast to the `emb` example, I use multi-phase initialization and introduce module state in a struct via `m_size` in my `PyModuleDef` instance.
So I would have liked to somehow pass data to my `Py_mod_exec` slot function to set it in my module state, but as the setup is made with raw C function pointers, I cannot see a way to pass data that way.
Alternatively, I've thought looking up the module after my `Py_Initialize` call and pass the data via `PyModule_GetState`, but I don't see how I can lookup my multi-phase initialized module.
So my idea now is to set some global state somewhere on the interpreter and pass the data that way. But I have not looked much into that yet, as I was hoping for a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Alternatively, I've thought looking up the module after my
> `Py_Initialize` call and pass the data via `PyModule_GetState`, but I
> don't see how I can lookup my multi-phase initialized module

I ended up with that solution and used `PyImport_ImportModule` to get a reference to the module.

See discussion on https://discuss.python.org/t/access-application-data-when-extending-embedded-python.